# #1064...........at ENGINE =MyISAM' at line 15

Tags: mysql

***Here is my code***

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `Employees` (

   `EmployeeID` VARCHAR( 6 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '',
   `FullName` VARCHAR( 35 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '',
   `EntryYMD` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0000-00-00',
   `PartTime` TINYINT( 3 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '100',
   `Mo` TINYINT( 1 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '8',
   `Tu` TINYINT( 1 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '8',
   `We` TINYINT( 1 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '8',
   `Th` TINYINT( 1 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '8',
   `Fr` TINYINT( 1 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '8',
   `Sa` TINYINT( 1 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',
   `Su` TINYINT( 1 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',
   `Version` INT( 8 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',
   `Changed` SMALLINT( 1 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '1',
   `Time_Stamp` TIMESTAMP( 14 ) NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (  `EmployeeID` ) ,
    ) ENGINE = MYISAM;
```

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(14) NOT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY  (`EmployeeID`),
)ENGINE =MyISAM' at line 15

Comment: remove last comma

Comment: PRIMARY KEY (  `EmployeeID` ) , <--- this last ,

Comment: already done but same error

Comment: I get a sql error 1426 too big precision 14 specified for  timestamp maximum is 6.